# validation failed for one or more entities Entity Framework in ASP .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, base64, savechanges

Exception was when i trying to save converted image to base64 format:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()) 
    {
        Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    var provider = GetMultipartProvider();

    var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    //Get Album name from Form
    var titleOfAlbum = GetTitleOfAlbum(provider);
    //get path to file
    var pathToCoverDecoded = result.FileData.First().LocalFileName;
    //ENCODE IMAGE TO BASE64
    var bMap = new Bitmap(pathToCoverDecoded);
    byte[] imageBtes;
    string base64;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bMap.Save(ms, bMap.RawFormat);
        imageBtes = ms.ToArray();
        base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBtes);
    }

    Album al = new Album();
    al.Title = titleOfAlbum;
    al.PathToCover = base64;
    db.Albums.Add(al);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Screenshot of exception message

[image]

Tell me please why i get this exception and  how i can resolve it ?

Comment: You can read validation message. Please provide it

Comment: As stated "See EntityValidationErrors" proeprty. It is fourth property above Message :)

Comment: Try to figure out for which field, the validation failed. This error has no relation to code.

Comment: i find error:**The field PathToCover must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '4000'.**

Comment: Check your input if you are passing the string array of length more than 4000.

Comment: @RachitGupta ok, I will check, but I was read post and understand what save images into database is not good idea, thanks for your comments.

Comment: who said that saving image to database is not a good idea

Comment: for example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field PathToCover must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '4000'